# Apache Knox: Advice on adding Ranger plugin

Tags: apache, security, hadoop2

I am looking for a way to add a Apache Ranger plugin to Apache Knox.
I couldn't really find a good starting point in the documentation (https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-5-0/dev-guide.html), so I was wondering if you guys had either added a plugin already or any idea where to start.

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

you can find the Knox plugin in the Ranger codebase. See the following installation instructions from the Ranger Installation Guide: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/RANGER/Ranger+Installation+Guide#RangerInstallationGuide-Install/ConfigureRangerKnoxPlugin

The following tutorial speaks to the same:
http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/manage-security-policy-hive-hbase-knox-ranger/

Here is another resource from a security workshop:
https://github.com/abajwa-hw/security-workshops/blob/master/Setup-knox-22.md

If you are actually looking to secure access to Ranger UI through the Knox Gateway then this JIRA will be of interest to you: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KNOX-707 it has already been resolved and will be released as part of 0.9.0 which is being tested and VOTEd on now.

Note that there are two options for authentication to Ranger in this feature:

1. Delegate the actual authentication to Ranger itself
2. Configure Ranger for KnoxSSO which will integrate with a third party identity provider, use form-based authentication against LDAP/AD, etc. The KnoxSSO cookie will then be used to establish a Ranger session.

Again, keep in mind that this is currently not in an Apache release but should be within a week or so.

Hope this is useful for you!

Comment: Hi lmccay, I think Fabian want's to secure the ranger web ui using not and not enabling the knox plugin for ranger :-)

Comment: @padmalcom - I have updated the answer with that context as well. Thanks for the interpretation. :)